Excessive API Requests While Zooming or Panning in flutter_map with Custom TileProvider
I am using the flutter_map package with TomTom tiles to display a map in my Flutter application (also for Windows). However, I noticed that zooming or panning the map triggers excessive API requests, leading to an overload of requests to the TomTom API.
i use it too for Windows application. I am using a custom TileProvider to fetch and cache map tiles. Here's my implementation
    TileLayer(
    tileBuilder: (context, tileWidget, tile) {
        return tileWidget;
    },
    tileProvider: CachedTileProvider(
        urlTemplate: "https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=$apiKey",
        apiKey: apiKey,
    ),
)

    class CachedTileProvider extends TileProvider {
    final String urlTemplate;
    final String apiKey;
    late CacheManager _cacheManager;

    CachedTileProvider({
        required this.urlTemplate,
        required this.apiKey,
    }) {
        _cacheManager = CacheManager(
            Config(
                'map_tiles_cache1',
                maxNrOfCacheObjects: 100000,
                stalePeriod: const Duration(minutes: 5),
            ),
        );
    }

    @override
    ImageProvider getImage(TileCoordinates coordinates, TileLayer options) {
        final url = getTileUrl(coordinates, options);

        return CachedNetworkImageProvider(
            url,
            cacheManager: _cacheManager,
        );
    }

    @override
    String getTileUrl(TileCoordinates coordinates, TileLayer options) {
        return urlTemplate
            .replaceAll('{x}', coordinates.x.toString())
            .replaceAll('{y}', coordinates.y.toString())
            .replaceAll('{z}', coordinates.z.toString())
            .replaceAll('$apiKey', apiKey);
    }
}

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return FlutterMap(
                options: MapOptions(
            minZoom: 11,
            initialCenter: LatLng(24.7136, 46.6753),
            initialZoom: 11,
            // Note: Zooming or panning triggers multiple requests
            onTap: (_, tappedPoint) => _handleMapTap(tappedPoint),
        ),
        children: [
            TileLayer(
                tileBuilder: (context, tileWidget, tile) {
                    return tileWidget;
                },
                tileProvider: CachedTileProvider(
                    urlTemplate: "https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=$apiKey",
                    apiKey: apiKey,
                ),
            ),
            TileLayer(
                tileProvider: CachedTileProvider(
                    urlTemplate: "https://api.tomtom.com/traffic/map/4/tile/flow/relative/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=$apiKey",
                    apiKey: apiKey,
                ),
            ),
        ],
    );
}

